# no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path - error message, unable to connect

Tags: oracle, database-connection

I am getting

```
no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path
```

when trying to connect to the oracle database and I am not sure why and how to correct the issue . I am using: Oracle SQL Developer and Oracle Client 11G. I need help on correcting this issue. I have edited the sqlnet.ora file to add the below details:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP,TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT)
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=2
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=45
```

However, I am still getting the error message. Apparently there is an LDAP.ORA file as well, but I don't know where it is and how to edit that file. It looks like I need to add below information

```
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT="###########"
DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (###########)
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

Also, my TNSNames.ora file is blank, I am not sure why it is blank. Maybe I need to install Oracle Client 11g or 12c again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I was connecting the wrong database instance. There are two similar databases: ###10### AND ###01###1. I needed to connect to ###10### not ###01###1 for the data that I need. The database instances are very similar and I connected to the wrong one.